# trying to display data from db using sql and php

Tags: php, sql

Seems pretty straightforward, but not getting an error or result.

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","***","***");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("ubook247", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM buzz_data
WHERE index=4");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['buzz_img'] . " " . $row['buzz_title'];
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

screenshot of db:

[image]

Comment: add an or die(mysql_error()) to the actual query.

Answer (score 3):

Index is a keyword in SQL, you'll need to escape it for the query to work. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM buzz_data WHERE `index` = 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Try editing the following row:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

into becoming like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

This makes php fetch an array with "labels" for the different fields, instead of naming them 0, 1, 2 and so on.

Comment: Sorry, no dice. I've also tried using other values from the table (WHERE buzz_title="4dfj") to no avail.

Comment: @ninetwozero, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php - are you sure that `mysql_fetch_array()` returns array with only numeric keys? Dont you talking about `mysql_fetch_row()`?

Comment: Oh shoot, I was certain that mysql_fetch_array returned numerics unless specified other (in parameter 2).

Comment: By default MYSQL_BOTH is set - it will return an array with numbers and labels.